# How to get the date on which the Python library was installed?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I know that `pip list` will list all the installed libraries and `pip show lib-name` will give details about the library like its dependecies, required-by and etc.

Is there a way to find the date on which the library was installed? Other than checking the date on which the particular library folder was created under `Lib\site-packages`.

This is solely out of curiosity.

Comment: There are pip UI tools to do that... or maybe if you use pycharm.. you'll get them easily

Answer (score 0):

There is no. `pip` doesn't maintain a separate database of packages. Said `site-packages` directory **is** that database. Some metadata are stored in `*.dist-info` directories but only that required for `pip` and `setuptools` to work. Installation date is not stored.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. Turns out that there is a tool for viewing the installed/last modified dates of pip packages. [A simple CLI tool to show the installation/modification times of all your pip packages](https://github.com/E3V3A/pip-date).